# ¿Cómo, a partir de un blucle (for o while) puedo hacer un arreglo que me permita ir anexando los datos que saca el bucole a un vector vacío en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

quisiera saber cómo puedo a partir de un bucle ir anexando datos a un vector vacío en R. En Python el arreglo lo hago con la función append, pero en Rstudio o R cómo es? Si alguien sabe le agradecería.

``

```
w_it<-1000
t<-5
pi<-0`
while(pi<t){
  pi<-pi+1
  indexacion<-runif(1,0,10)
  tirn<-runif(1,-0.02,0.07)
  w_it<-w_it+w_it*indexacion*tirn
  print(indexacion)
  print(tirn)
  print(w_it)
  if(pi==t){
    print("Acabamos")
}'
```

Al terminar de correr el bucle cuando pi==t él imprime unos datos, pero cómo puedo coger esos datos y meterlos a un vector vacío o a una matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que siempre es importante en estos casos, es evitar el uso de `c()` dentro del ciclo, ya que estaríamos copiando objetos todo el tiempo, y a medida que se va creciendo en el tamaño, esto puede ser una penalidad importante en la performance. En tu ejemplo te sugiero usar una lista:

```
datos <- list()
while(pi<t){
  pi<-pi+1
  indexacion<-runif(1,0,10)
  tirn<-runif(1,-0.02,0.07)

  datos[[pi]] <- cbind(indexacion, tirn, w_it)
}
```

Y finalmente, puedes transformar la lista en una matriz más legible, dónde cada fila representa los datos de una iteración:

```
do.call(rbind, datos)

     indexacion        tirn w_it
[1,]   8.407039  0.00464930 1000
[2,]   7.839702  0.05890301 1000
[3,]   3.108229 -0.01130515 1000
[4,]   9.564813 -0.01449118 1000
[5,]   2.104195  0.05253621 1000
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, era exactamente lo que buscaba,